# High Current Step-Down Conversion 12V-5V/100A

Tags: power-supply, buck, high-current

I inherited two 12 V, 1200 W server power supplies a while back and I'd like to press them into service as electrolysis cell power supplies for making (per)chlorates.  I need to drop the output to ~5 V while ideally keeping the same current capacity.  Even better would be a means to adjust the output voltage with the 2-6 V range or run in constant-current mode, but that's not strictly necessary.

Having looked for buck converters to fulfill this purpose, I've come up more or less empty-handed.  I saw a couple pricey units that seemed like they might do the job, but for the cost I'd just buy a new MeanWell supply.

I was hoping someone here might be able to guide me in the right direction on how I might accomplish what I'm after.  I have some hobby-level electronics knowledge if a converter of some kind is feasible, I wanted to discuss with people more knowledgeable first given that I've never worked on circuits anywhere near this level of power before.

It seems like Analog Devices might offer some regulators that could handle the task, but my experience designing SMPSs is quite limited, so again I'm just looking for a sanity check on whether I'm potentially wasting my time trying to pursue this.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148013/discussion-on-question-by-franklin-knight-high-current-step-down-conversion-12v); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly left-field, but you could add two electrolysis cells in series, which would give roughly 6V on each cell, with no change to PSU.  This might be good enough for you, with the extra overvoltage not being an issue.  If 4V was okay, then 3 cells in series would do what you need.